# can this be calculated without using two for loops

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I have the following  structure of data in an array  and I am trying to calculate the total duration:

```
 $elements = array(
                        'elementfrom-work' => "09:00",
                        'elementto-work' => "17:00",
                        'elementdays-work' => "5",

                        'elementfrom-karate' => "18:00",
                        'elementto-karate' => "20:00",
                        'elementdays-karate' => "3",

                        'elementfrom-stamp' => "21:00",
                        'elementto-stamp' => "22:00",
                        //it doest have the default days 'elementdays-stamp' set
                         //so it will take the default 7
                        'element-simple1' => "4", //it will take the default 7
                        'element-simple2' => "8",  //it will take the default 7
                        'element-simple3' => "1",
                        'elementdays-simple3' => "1", //day is set
    );
```

I have managed to do it but my code is messy, for each item it gets the sub string and runs another for loop to check if any other elements exists when it is not simple (like days) .

I am trying to calculate for each item the total duration e.g outcome is:

```
Work:40
Karate:6
Stamp:7
Simple1=28
Simple2=56
Simple3=1

total duration:138
```

Can this be done without two for loops and how ? If it is not possible how would you calculate it.

Comment: If possible, you may want to consider using sub arrays to reduce the complexity of finding common keys.  For example: work, karate, stamp etc should all be a sub array containing the key => values for the day and time.  You can even make those keys semantic so their is no confusion: `from`, `to`, `days`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found this problem quite interesting, so you can do something like:

```
$elements[] = array(
    'elementfrom-work' => "09:00",
    'elementto-work' => "17:00",
    'elementdays-work' => "7",

    'elementfrom-karate' => "18:00",
    'elementto-karate' => "20:00",
    'elementdays-karate' => "3",

    'elementfrom-stamp' => "21:00",
    'elementto-stamp' => "22:00",

    'a' => "21:00",
    'b' => "22:00"
);
```

And use those two functions:

```
function negative($x)
{
    if($x < 0)
    {
        return -$x;
    }
    return $x;
}

function isTime($string)
{
    $split = explode(":", $string);

    if(isset($split[1]))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

foreach($elements as $key => $val)
{
    $total = 0;
    $temp = 0;
    $i = 0;
    foreach($val as $innerKey => $time)
    {
        $isTime = isTime($time);
        $split = explode(":", $time);
        $h = $split[0];

        switch($i)
        {
            case 0:
                $temp -= $h;
                break;

            case 1:
                $temp += $h;
                break;

            case 2:
                if($isTime)
                {
                    $mult = $temp *= 7;
                    $unsigned = negative($mult);
                    $total += $unsigned;
                    $temp = 0;
                    $temp -= $h;
                    $i = 0;
                    break;
                }
                $mult = $temp *= $h;
                $unsigned = negative($mult);
                $total += $unsigned;
                $temp = 0;
                $i = -1;
                break;

            default:
                 break;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    echo $total;
}
```

Your idea of the carry is a bit funky but something like that should work.

Comment: You're welcome, please up vote it if it was helpful, note that I haven't tested it 100% but I did some demos :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you know the expected name of the days item... check if it's exists instead of looping, iterate the array keys, when you get to "elementfrom-work" you can check if array got key  "elementdays-work" instead of re iterate to search this item in N level complexity...